# How to register GADNativeAd to auto handle GADNativeContentAd view click in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, admob

We're working on implementing native ads - `GADNativeContentAd`. I have displayed it well with all its fields. Now, I want to handle click action on ad view but it seems that it is not auto handled by google, same as banner ads. (Clicking on ad view should automatically take me to a web browser with a url in it.)

I have fill the following with sample urls in console to test, but no luck. Please guide.

```
Deep link click action URL
Fallback click action URL
Third party impression tracker
Third party click tracker
```

**When ad is received, below is my code.**

```
(void)adLoader:(GADAdLoader *)adLoader didReceiveNativeContentAd:(GADNativeContentAd *)nativeContentAd  
{  
     NativeContentAd *myNativeAd = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ContentAdView" owner:nil options:nil] firstObject];  

    // Associate the content ad view with the content ad object.  
    // This is required to make the ad clickable.  
    myNativeAd.nativeContentAd = nativeContentAd;

    // Populate the app install ad view with the app install ad assets.  
    ((UILabel *)myNativeAd.HeadLine).text = nativeContentAd.headline;  
    ((UILabel *)myNativeAd.Body).text = nativeContentAd.body;  
    [((UIButton *)myNativeAd.InstallButton) setTitle:nativeContentAd.callToAction forState:UIControlStateNormal];  
    ((UIImageView *)myNativeAd.LogoImage).image = ((GADNativeAdImage *)[nativeContentAd.images firstObject]).image;

    // Add appInstallAdView to the view controller's view.  
    [self.myNativeAdPlaceholder addSubview:myNativeAd];  
}
```

Comment: any solution here?

Comment: Yes. For GADNativeContentAd. there was issue with my xib and for GADNativeCustomTemplateAd, I used
[myCustomTemplateAd performClickOnAssetWithKey:@"Image" customClickHandler:^{
}];